# Gitlab CD for iOS on server

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to create Continuous Deployment pipeline for an iOS project with Gitlab tools.

It's suggested to use **own mac** in order to run tests and **Archive** in [this tutorial](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/).

So, there, probably, should be a way to create runner on a server, not on own machine, right? Because otherwise the owner of the Apple distribution signature would be the onlyone who can trigger deployment process.